# What are the leaf values in sklearn GBDT, and How do I obtain them?

Tags: tree, scikit-learn, boosting

I can export structure of a GBDT to a image with [the tree.export_graphviz function](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.export_graphviz.html):

``` Python3

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier

clf = GradientBoostingClassifier(n_estimators=1) # set to 1 for the sake of simplicity
iris = load_iris()

clf = clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
tree.export_graphviz(clf.estimators_[0,0], out_file='tree.dot')
check_call(['dot','-Tpng','tree.dot','-o','tree.png'])
```

```

[This is the obtained image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sN9Rf.png)

I wondering what are the `value` on the leafs? and How can I obtain them?

I have tried the `apply` and `decision_function` functions, neither works.

Comment: Value is the number of samples belonging to that or its child nodes.

Comment: @VivekKumar Instead of `samples`, I mean `value` which can be negative. Just check the above image.

Comment: Ohk. What do you get when you do `export_graphviz(..., proportion = True)`. Looks like its the weight of those samples.

Comment: Yes, the `samples` line would be the weights of samples. But what I am asking is the last line (`value=2.0`, `value=-1.0`, ...). Please read the above figure before comment again, thanks.

Comment: I get that. And I am talking about that only. Those two things are related. `samples and value`. And I am saying that `value` is the weight on that node for those samples. `samples` represent the number of samples.

Comment: If someone is having difficulty using `check_call()`, you can import this function by typing `from subprocess import check_call` at the top of your python file to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access leave properties of each individual tree using its internal object `tree_` and its attributes. `export_graphviz` uses exactly this approach.

Consider this code. For each attribute, it gives an array of its values over all the tree nodes:

```
print(clf.estimators_[0,0].tree_.feature)
print(clf.estimators_[0,0].tree_.threshold)
print(clf.estimators_[0,0].tree_.children_left)
print(clf.estimators_[0,0].tree_.children_right)
print(clf.estimators_[0,0].tree_.n_node_samples)
print(clf.estimators_[0,0].tree_.value.ravel())
```

The output will be

```
[ 2 -2 -2]
[ 2.45000005 -2.         -2.        ]
[ 1 -1 -1]
[ 2 -1 -1]
[150  50 100]
[  3.51570624e-16   2.00000000e+00  -1.00000000e+00]
```

That is, your tree has 3 nodes, and the first one compares the value of feature `2` with `2.45`, etc.

The values in the root node, left and right leaf are `3e-16`, `2`, and `-1` respectively.

These values, although, are not obvious to interpret, because the tree has tried to predict the gradient of GBDT loss function.

Comment: How can I get all the attributes of `tree_`?

Comment: ```dir(tree_)``` produces list of all the attributes, see the docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir